# How can I tail logs from OpenShift to be verbose about python setup.py, virtualenv, and pip?

Tags: python, flask, openshift

When I run:

```
rhc tail -a myapp
```

I do see a stream of log messages at app startup, but nothing about the setup of the virtualenv and installation of dependencies in requirements.txt, like flask etc. How can I better monitor this on the server for the purposes of debugging, in case I run into a problem?  This is fairly easy to do in Heroku, but I'm considering migrating apps to OpenShift, but only if options for debugging python are very flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `git push` changes to your app you OpenShift responds with detailed output regarding the status of setup.py, requirements.txt, etc. Here is sample (abbreviated) output from a deployment to a Python app on OpenShift:

```
$ git commit -m "Adds BeautifulSoup"
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
...
remote: Stopping Python 3.3 cartridge
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
...
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 8d92954
remote: Activating virtenv
remote: Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..
...
remote: Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/553fde444382eca8a0000028/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
...
remote: Downloading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/packages/source/b/beautifulsoup4/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz (143kB)
remote: Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
remote: Running setup.py install for beautifulsoup4
remote: Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.3.2
remote: Running setup.py script..
remote: running develop
remote: running egg_info
remote: creating YourAppName.egg-info
remote: writing top-level names to YourAppName.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote: writing YourAppName.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote: writing dependency_links to YourAppName.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote: writing manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: running build_ext
remote: Creating /var/lib/openshift/553fde444382eca8a0000028/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/YourAppName.egg-link (link to .)
remote: Adding YourAppName 1.0 to easy-install.pth file
remote: Installed /var/lib/openshift/553fde444382eca8a0000028/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: Processing dependencies for YourAppName==1.0
remote: Finished processing dependencies for YourAppName==1.0
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is d9c707fb
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting Python 3.3 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
remote: Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: Application "wsgi.py" selected as default WSGI entry point
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

Comment: Yes you are 100% right.  I was so busy looking at my tail log i forgot to look at this in my other shell window....doh! ;)

Comment: Accept the answer if you get a chance, trying to work my way over 1k rep on stack :)

Comment: Opps, sorry about that . By accident, I clicked the up arrow on April 30th instead of the checkmark.  And a well earned checkmark it is. Thanks for the reminder luciddreamz  :)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do imo in this case is to ssh into your gear. Once logged in you can change into the app directory and view all log/config files directly.

Comment: It's so nice to be able to tail logs locally though. Since I can tail logs from the server using the above command, logically it must be some type of setting that is required to simply make the output more verbose.  Why would rhc otherwise include the "tail" command?